# How to disable default Insert key behaviour in CodeMirror?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'am using CodeMirror for code editing and when I press INS (insert key) it behaves like in any normal text editor, switching between overtype and insert mode, but I don't want that.

I want it to be like in normal `<textarea>`, without any change actually.

Can I do that somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used CodeMirror, but there is a function in the documentation that toggles overwrite/normal insert mode
(https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#usage):

```
cm.toggleOverwrite(?value: boolean)
    Switches between overwrite and normal insert mode (when not given an argument), or sets the overwrite mode to a specific state (when given an argument).
```

You could listen for the user to press the `insert` key and override the value passed into that function to make it stay as normal insert mode.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @httpNick's answer, this snippet should remap the Insert key to not toggle the overwrite (or rather, to explicitly make it NOT overwrite).

```js
editor.setOption("extraKeys", {
    Insert: (cm) => {
        cm.toggleOverwrite(false);
    }
});
```

This is where the docs explain Key Maps: https://codemirror.net/5/doc/manual.html#keymaps

The "Insert" key is from this key map: https://codemirror.net/5/doc/manual.html#commands